# import for front end development

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I would like to use the features of ES2016 for my front end development. Especially `import` and `decorators` are interesting for me.

I’ve started a small test project and created some different files with classes which I include with `import`. Babel generates the correct files but includes an `require` statement which does not work in a browser (as far as I know).

Are there any good tools to concat all files into a single javascript file ordered by their require? Or some libraries for gulp which do this for me?

Comment: what module bundler tool (gulp/webpack/etc) do you use?

Comment: @MaximKuzmin currently gulp and i would like to stay with this. I don't want to rewrite all my building scripts but if there is no good library for gulp I would change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because `Babel` translates your `ES2016` code into `CommonJS` format, browser does not support it. You need some module bundler for creating bundle that can be used in browser:

- Browserify
- Webpack
- Rollup

Example `gulp` build with [gulp-rollup](https://github.com/mcasimir/gulp-rollup)

```
// setup by `npm i gulp gulp-rollup rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2016 babel-plugin-external-helpers --save-dev`

// gulpfile.js
var gulp       = require('gulp'),
    rollup     = require('gulp-rollup');

gulp.task('bundle', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/**/*.js')
    // transform the files here.
    .pipe(rollup({
      // any option supported by Rollup can be set here.
      "format": "iife",
      "plugins": [
        require("rollup-plugin-babel")({
          "presets": [["es2016", { "modules": false }]],
          "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
        })
      ],
      entry: './src/main.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: @pablo-christiano obviousely you should use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2016 instead of babel-preset-es2015

Comment: Thanks for your help! this looks like exactly what i needed. I'm new to babel. Will there be any conflicts if i use the `stage-2` preset and the `transform-decorators-legacy` plugin within?